# Way to load folder as module constant in rails app directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So have a rails 5 project and would like to load a directory like this

```
/app
  /services
    /user
      foo.rb
```

as the constant ::Services::User::Foo

Does anyone have experience in getting rails autoload paths to load the constants in this manner?

---

foo.rb

```
module Services
  module User
    class Foo

    end
  end
end
```

SOLUTION

Add this to your application.rb file

`config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app')`

See discussions here on autoloading

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14382#issuecomment-37763348
 https://github.com/trailblazer/trailblazer/issues/89#issuecomment-149367035

Comment: What's inside `foo.rb`? A class, a module, loose methods?

Comment: How is the class named? `Foo`, not inside a module?

Comment: It would be a class that is underneath the modules (Services::User), just updated question with example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Auto loading

You need to define `Services::User::Foo` inside `app/services/services/user/foo.rb`

If you don't want this weird subfolder duplication, you could also move `services` to `app/models/services` or `lib/services`.

You could also leave `foo.rb` in `app/services/user/foo.rb`, but it should define `User::Foo`.

## Eager loading

If you don't need any magic with namespaces and class names, it is pretty straightforward :

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app/services/**/*.rb')].each{|rb| require rb}
```

This will eagerly load any Ruby script inside `app/services` and any subfolder.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, i am wanting this to go with the autoload paths so that it is reloaded on file changes, when i do this 
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[File.join(Rails.root,'app/services')] the constants don't show up

Comment: For the Autoloading example above, that should work out of the box without having to add to the autoload_paths b/c all folders in the app directory are there by default.  My thought was that there had to be a way to do that without the double nesting

Comment: Subfolders in `app` are not treated equally. `app/models/user.rb` does not define `Models::User` but just `User` for example.

Comment: Cool, i see/understand what you are saying.   I was thinking that there might be some way to tell ActiveSupport to load a folder as a module.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14382#issuecomment-37763348 this may do it, will check here in a bit and update

Comment: No need to add `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/services')` actually.

Comment: Adding `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app')` does the trick that will load the services folder as a module and loads all the other stuff normally (models/controllers/etc)