# Rails namespace service objects in app/services folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, autoload

I'm trying to put service objects into `app/services` folder but reference them via `Services::SomeModel::SomeClass` to better organize my code (the project is pretty large).

```
# app/services/tasks/create.rb
module Services
  module Tasks
    class Create
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

However, because of the way Rails loads the files, `app/services` is treated like a base folder and Rails keeps wanting the classes to be defined as `::Tasks::Create` instead of `::Services::Tasks::Create`.

I can solve this by placing my service objects in a subdirectory, like `app/classes/services` and then referencing them via `::Services::Tasks::Create`, but I would prefer to have the `/services` folder in the `/app` directory itself.

I'm not a huge fan of the convention some use with services, naming them `::Tasks::CreateService`.  The whole reason I'm namespacing them the way I am is so anyone can look at the code and understand where the related files are located and to keep everything organized.

I've tried playing with `auto_load` in the `config/application.rb` file but that doesn't seem to work, since Rails is already pre-loading the files in `app/*` (that's my understanding).

Is there a way to reference service objects via `::Services::Model::Action` and have the files located in `app/services/model/action.rb`?

Comment: I use the exact same structure you seem to be having an issue with...but I don't have any issues... I reference them as `Services::Tasks::Create` though (no leading ::)..not sure that it matters for your issue or not

Comment: It seems I have to auto_load the `/app` directory, which I thought was already done by Rails...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921032/way-to-load-folder-as-module-constant-in-rails-app-directory works, but I don't know "why".